# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pip

I have all packages installed, but when I tried to import `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup4` and I got this error `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup4 ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup4' from 'bs4' (C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py)`

Does anyone know why am getting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` instead.

Reviewing the [documentation for Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), their examples import using a module name of BeautifulSoup, not BeautifulSoup**4**.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that the normal response to questions that are caused by a simple typo or basic misunderstanding is to flag the question for closure, and [not to answer the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260104/dissuade-answers-to-simple-typos/269237#269237). This is because typo questions are rarely useful for future visitors to Stack Overflow.